# How to sort a list of objects in kotlin?

Tags: android, list, sorting, kotlin

I have a list of objects like this:

```
 [
    {
      "Price": 2100000,
      "Id": "5f53787e871ebc4bda455927"
    },
    {
      "Price": 2089000,
      "Id": "5f7da4ef7a0ad2ed730416f8"
    },
    {
   
      "Price": 0,
      "Id": "5f82b1189c333dab0b1ce3c5"
    }
 ]
```

How can I sort this list by price value of objects and then pass it to my adapter?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have an object like this:

```
class YourClass(
  val price: Int,
  val id: String
)
```

You can sort by price in two ways:

**Mutable**

```
val yourMutableList: MutableList<YourClass> = mutableListOf()
yourMutableList.sortBy { it.price }
// now yourMutableList is sorted itself
```

**Not mutable**

```
val yourList: List<YourClass> = listOf()
val yourSortedList: List<YourClass> = yourList.sortedBy { it.price }
```

As you can see, in the second sample, you have to save the result in a new list. Because **List** is immutable, therefore it **cannot be altered** and **it is necessary to create a new list**.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Im new to kotlin so I have to ask for a little more clarification.
I am getting the list like this:

` productDetailViewModel.productLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { item ->

            productStoresAdapter.stores = item.sameProducts as ArrayList<SameProduct>`

Here I need to sort 'item.sameProducts' with the values I wrote on the question. Would you please help me more on this?

Comment: You can save first your List and then sort it. For example: **List<SameProduct> sameProducts = item.sameProducts as ArrayList<SameProduct>**, and then put the list sorted in your adapter, **productStoresAdapter.stores = sameProducts.sortedBy { it.Price }**

Comment: Dear Jose I did what you said but I got this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: In order to help you I would need to know the type of **item.sameProducts**.

Comment: Please, complete your main question above with more detail about SameProduct class and the call to your ViewModel. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple example to sort by your choice of order:

```
class Pizza(
  val price: Double
)

val regularSlice = Pizza(price = 2.75)
val extraCheeseSlice = Pizza(price = 3.75)
val pepperoniSlice = Pizza(price = 4.75)

val list = ArrayList<Pizza>()
list.add(extraCheeseSlice)
list.add(pepperoniSlice)
list.add(regularSlice)
```

This is the same exact list sorted in place:

```
list.sortBy { it.price } // lowest to highest - result is: regularSlice, extraCheeseSlice, pepperoniSlice

list.sortByDescending { it.price } // highest to lowest - result is: pepperoniSlice, extraCheeseSlice, regularSlice
```

If you want a new list just use `sortedBy`:

```
val newListFromLowestToHighest = list.sortedBy { it.price } // result is: regularSlice, extraCheeseSlice, pepperoniSlice
    
val newListFromHighestToLowest = list.sortByDescending { it.price } // result is: pepperoniSlice, extraCheeseSlice, regularSlice
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a class that represents your elements like this:

```
data class Element (
    val price: Int, 
    val id: String
)
```

And given a list of those from your deserializer:

```
val listOfElements: List<Element> = ...
```

You can obtain a new list sorted by price as follows:

```
val sortedByPrice = listOfElements.sortedBy { it.price }
```

Try it in the Kotlin Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/TBIdxsaoi

Comment: thanks for your answer. Im new to kotlin so I have to ask for a little more clarification.
I am getting the list like this:

` productDetailViewModel.productLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { item ->

            productStoresAdapter.stores = item.sameProducts as ArrayList<SameProduct>`

Here I need to sort 'item.sameProducts' with the values I wrote on the question. Would you please help me more on this?